# Android - Error using using Emotionsense

Tags: android, sensors

I am trying to use a library to collect sensor data (http://emotionsense.github.io/android.html). I am following their guide, but I get an error with the "context" variable. It says "cannot resolve symbol context" I don't understand why as I am following their guide.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_esensor);
    ESSensorManager sm = ESSensorManager.getSensorManager(context);

}
```

Comment: Is this code inside an Activity? pass `this` instead of `context`. If instead you're in a fragment pass `getContext()`. The explanation is that in their DOCs they say they need a context (an object of the Android framework), every activity is a `context` itself and every fragment, being attached to an activity can retrieve the context with the `getContext()` method

Comment: It is an Activity. When I pass this, it suggests to surround the line with try catch

Comment: Maybe because the `getSensorManager()` method can throw an exception. Surround it as the editor suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_esensor);
    try{
        ESSensorManager sm = ESSensorManager.getSensorManager(getApplicationContext());
    }catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();       
    }
}
```